# Formatting a social security number using a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to format a Social Security number from a string that is passed in to the method as an argument:

```
def format_ssns(string)
  ssn = /\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/
  return string.gsub(/(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3') 
end
```

I don't understand why this is not formatting my SSN when I test with:

```
format_ssns("234601422, 350.80.0744, 013-60-8762")
```

Comment: Learn [regex the easy way](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and test it on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com)

Comment: You don't need `return` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement *is* done for the last SSN only. You need to tell the regex that there may be other chars than `-` between the different digit groups.

Use this instead:

```
(\d{3})[^\d]?(\d{2})[^\d]?(\d{4})
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://codepad.org/I1gUeeE0

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but for some reason that only returns the last value in that string. I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong. Also what is the first part (.*?) doing?

Comment: But what about if I wanted to format the other incorrectly formatted values that have been passed into the method? The only thing that I'm getting back is 013-60-8762 which is the last value and is already formatted correctly.

Comment: @user2197606 Ok, sorry I misunderstood. Check out my new demo.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Sorry to be annoying but I really want to understand why this worked. What did this [^\d]? do?

Comment: @user2197606 `[^\d]?` means `Any chars but no digits or no chars at all`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in your code. The first, is that your regexp expects the input to be already in the format

```
\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d
```

which is indeed not true and it would not make sense, given this is the format you want to achieve.
What you should do is first normalize the input to a list of digits

```
234601422 -> 234601422
350.80.0744 -> 350800744
013-60-8762 -> 013608762
```

then format the string.

```
def format_ssns(input)
  string = input
  string.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '')
  string.gsub!(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3') 
  string
end
```